# Regex to find certain phone numbers in a damaged file

Tags: regex

I have the following task:

Use grep with the -Pao options and a regular expression to extract all phone numbers from the broken file (solution: 13 phone numbers). The regular expression should match as closely as possible the following formats of phone numbers and be as short as possible:

[image]

I tried to work with the respective beginning of the numbers, to then put them together and keep moving forward.

I now have the following code:

`grep -Pao '(\+\d{2}.) | (\d{3,4}) | (\d\s\d{2})' kaputt.txt`

(the mode is PCRE)

Unfortunately, the code does not return the desired results, as it seems that search conditions are mutually exclusive. I would therefore be grateful for help here.

Comment: "As short as possible" is a little contradictory to not knowing what constitutes a "valid number" For example, if you know that a valid number cannot have slashes, It may be shorter to forbid a slash rather than trying to match the pattern with an slash in it. The shortest solution is probably to match the valid numbers and inverse the match with `-v`

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/WOyTM5/1) does it, but it is not short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there blanks on both sides of the pipes? If yes, the first case actually is (+\d{2}.)\s which doesn't match any of the formats.

https://regex101.com/r/qDmGIC/1 - but it will also match come unwanted combinations like 111 (1)11 11

`^((\+\d{2})|(\d{3,4}))[\s-](\(?(\d\))?\d{2}\)?|\d|\d{5})[\s-]((\d{5})(\s(-\s)?|-)\d{2}|\d{6,7}|\d{2})`

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I'm going to think about your propositions and in case I have further questions, I'm going to contact you again.
And also thank you that you have put in the effort of typing what was shown on the picture. I didn't consider that these lines have to be written out but next time I'm going to print the lines too.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a fool's errand to try and find the absolute shortest regex possible. The following should be fine as no format seems to be an extension of another.

```sh
grep -Pao "(?:\+\d\d \d\d \d{7}|\+\d\d (\d\d) \d{5} \- \d\d|\+\d\d (\d)\d\d \d{5}\-\d\d|\+\d\d-\d\d\-\d{7}|\+\d\d \d\d \d{5}\-\d\d|\d{4} \d \d{6}|\d \d\d \/ \d\d \d\d \d\d|\d{8}\-\d\d)" kaputt.txt
```

It is just the text extracted from your image (!) of the required formats, with `x` replaced by `\d`, `-` replaced by `\-`, `+` replaced by `\+`, and with each format alternative separated by `|`.

If you want to match across lines then the `-z` flag is required and each space could be replaced with, for example, `\s+`.